# Grouping objects of different types based on common fields

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I want to group different objects types based on same content of fields `incomeCode`, `endDate` and `codeRef` on both classes. I omitted many fields on both classes that make each object unique for simplicity.

```
public class Exon  {

    private Long id;

    private IncomeCode incomeCode;

    private LocalDate endDate;

    String codeRef;

}   

public class Sup {

    private Long id;

    private IncomeCode incomeCode;

    private LocalDate startDate;

    private LocalDate endDate;

    String codeRef;

}
```

Exons example:

| id | incomdeCode | endDate | codeRef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 01/01/2021 | 4 |
| 2 | 21 | 01/01/2022 | 5 |
| 3 | 33 | 01/01/2023 | 2 |
| 4 | 45 | 01/01/2021 | 4 |

Sups example:

| id | incomdeCode | endDate | codeRef |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 01/01/2021 | 4 |
| 2 | 21 | 01/01/2022 | 5 |
| 3 | 33 | 01/01/2023 | 2 |

Desired result :
List : { {exon1, exon4, sup1}, {exon2, sup2}, {exon3, sup3} }

My attempt :

```
public Map<Object, List<Exon>> getExons() {
    Map<Object, List<Exon>> result = getSource1.stream()
            .flatMap(lp -> lp.getExons().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> new KeyGroup(e.getIncomeCode(), e.getEndDate(), e.getCodeRef())
            ));
    return result;
  }

public Map<Object, List<Sup>> getSups() {
        Map<Object, List<Sup>> result = getSource2.stream()
                .flatMap(lp -> lp.getSups().stream())
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> new 
KeyGroup(e.getIncomeCode(), e.getEndDate(), e.getCodeRef())));
        return result;
   }

 Map<Object, List<Exon>> exonList = getExons();
 Map<Object, List<Sup>> supList = getSups();
 Map<Object, List<List<?>>> objMap = new HashMap<>();

exonList.forEach((k, v) -> {
        if (objMap.containsKey(o)) {
            objMap.get(o).add(v);
        } else {
            List<List<?>> eList = new ArrayList<>();
            eList.add(v);
            objMap.put(o, eList);
        }

    });

    supList.forEach((o, v) -> {
        if (objMap.containsKey(o)) {
            objMap.get(o).add(v);
        } else {
            List<List<?>> eList = new ArrayList<>();
            eList.add(v);
            objMap.put(o, eList);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What should be the resulting type of the list? According to the provided class definitions `exon` and `sup` have no common super type apart from `Object`. BTW, class names by convention should start in with upper-case letter.

Comment: It would also be nicer if you would share your attempt to approach this problem.

Comment: Yes, exon and sup don't extend any super type apart from Object. The resulting type of list is of type Object

Comment: That would not give any advantage, I mean you'll be unable to access the data of this object without casting. Using `Object` as generic type is as bad as not use generics at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been pointed out in the comments, if you need to mix different type of objects your resulting `List` will be a `List<List<Object>>`.

To group them by like that, you could use the `collect()` terminal operation in conjunction with a `Collectors.groupingBy()` which could group the objects with a key built ad-hoc with the desired fields (`incomeCode`, `endDate` and `codeRef`). After building the `Map`, you could retrieve its values, i.e. a `Collection` with the lists of objects, and give them in input to the Conversion Constructor of a `List` implementation.

```
List<List<Object>> listRes = new ArrayList<>(Stream.concat(listExon.stream(), listSup.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(obj -> {
            if (obj instanceof Exon) {
                Exon exon = (Exon) obj;
                return String.format("%s-%s-%s", exon.getIncomeCode(), exon.getEndDate(), exon.getCodeRef());
            }
            Sup sup = (Sup) obj;
            return String.format("%s-%s-%s", sup.getIncomeCode(), sup.getEndDate(), sup.getCodeRef());
        })).values());
```

Here there is also a link to test the code above:

https://ideone.com/OSTItQ

Comment: Thank you so much Dan, this is the expected solution. I'm wondering now when and how i can transform each group of objects [Exon{45 2021-01-01 4}, Exon{45 2021-01-01 4}, Sup{45 2021-01-01 4}] and
[Exon{33 2023-01-01 2}, Sup{33 2023-01-01 2}] and
[Exon{21 2022-01-01 5}, Sup{21 2022-01-01 5}] to a new object type called GlobalData. I have already a solution using a foreach loop to transform each group to his correspending GlobalData object. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: @user3072470 make a new question linking the current one. I'll be more than happy to help you.

Comment: Hi Dan, I asked a new question and here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/q/72372658/3072470

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this. You can make another subclass and group your different class item on this map

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Solution
{

    public void sol()
    {
        List<Exon> exons = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Sup> sups = new ArrayList<>();

        List<ClassWithNeededFields> list1 = exons.stream()
        .map(item -> new ClassWithNeededFields(item.getIncomeCode(), "neededField"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        List<ClassWithNeededFields> list2 = sups.stream()
        .map(item -> new ClassWithNeededFields(item.getIncomeCode(), "neededField"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        list1.addAll(list2);
        
        Map<IncomeCode, List<ClassWithNeededFields>> map2 = list1.stream()
                .map(item -> new ClassWithNeededFields(item.getIncomeCode(), "neededField"))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ClassWithNeededFields::getIncomeCode));

    }

    public class Exon
    {
        private IncomeCode incomeCode;

        public IncomeCode getIncomeCode()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class Sup
    {
        private IncomeCode incomeCode;

        public IncomeCode getIncomeCode()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public class IncomeCode
    {

    }

    public class ClassWithNeededFields
    {
        private IncomeCode incomeCode;

        private String otherField;

        // The other needed fields. ...

        public ClassWithNeededFields(IncomeCode incomeCode, String otherField /* The other needed fields. ... */)
        {

        }

        public IncomeCode getIncomeCode()
        {
            return this.incomeCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: gunescelil: i can't modify the Exon and Sup classes

Comment: Maybe you can declare a new class and only add the needed fields to that class. First you can map your Exon and Sup classes to that new Class and make a list and then you can group them

Comment: I edited my solution