# How and when transform a list of grouped list of objects of different types

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I'm wondering WHEN (just after grouping and before collecting to `List<List<Object>>`) and HOW (re-stream the collected groups after collecting them).

Can I transform each sub-list of objects

```
[Exon{45 2021-01-01 4}, Exon{45 2021-01-01 4}, Sup{45 2021-01-01 4}] 
and 
[Exon{33 2023-01-01 2}, Sup{33 2023-01-01 2}] 
and 
[Exon{21 2022-01-01 5}, Sup{21 2022-01-01 5}]
```

into a new object type called `GlobalData`?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

This question is linked to my previous question :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72368904/3072470

Here is the code provided by Dan for grouping my different Objects into a list of objects collected to a list:
https://ideone.com/OSTItQ

```
public class GlobalData {

private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

private IncomeCode incomeCode;

private LocalDate endDate;

private String codeRef;

private boolean taxable;

private String pw = "";

private BigDecimal area = BigDecimal.ZERO;

//private BigDecimal taxableIncome = BigDecimal.ZERO;

private BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.ZERO;

private BigDecimal exonValueType = BigDecimal.ZERO;

private BigDecimal Income = BigDecimal.ZERO;

private BigDecimal exemptedIncome = BigDecimal.ZERO;

private BigDecimal refIncome = BigDecimal.ZERO;
 
}

List<GlobalData> globalTaxDataList = listRes.stream()
            .map(this::toGlobalData)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

private GlobalData toGlobalData(List<Object> objects) {
        GlobalData globalData = new GlobalData();
        objects // list of mix Exons and Sups objects (Exon and Sup contain more, fields incomeCode, endDate and codeRef are used only for grouping) ex: [Exon{45 2021-01-01 4}, Exon{45 2021-01-01 4}, Sup{45 2021-01-01 4}]
            .forEach(o -> {
                if (o instanceof Exon) {
                  globalData.setValue(globalData.getValue()
                     .add(o.getValue()))
                   if (o.getxxx()> 100) {
                     globalData.setIncome(globalData.getIncome()
                      .add(calcMethod(o)))
                   }
                   //more business code here
                }

                if (o instanceof Sup) {     
                   globalData.setValue(globalData.getValue()
                    .add(o.getValue()))
                   if (o.getxxx()> 100) {
                      globalData.setIncome(globalData.getIncome()
                         .add(calcMethod(o)))
                   }
                   //more business code here
                }
            });
    return globalData;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't really matter when or how you do it. Though if you convert before grouping, then the grouping might have been easier

Comment: Can you provide the class definition of `GlobalData`?

Comment: I added the GlobalData class defintion to the post. The transformation will use all the objects of each group to construct the GlobalData object. For our example the result of transformation will be a list of 3 GlobalData objects

Comment: @user3072470 In your previous post, Exon and Sup's id was a Long, while here for GlobalData is a UUID. Is it a typo and GlobalData has a Long id too or we don't need to bring the Exon's and Sup's id when creating a new GlobalData?

Comment: I don't need the ids of Exons and Sups for transformation. I need the groups to build my new GlobalData objects, i'm wondering if it's possible to do this transformation  like this List<GlobalData> listRes = new ArrayList<>(Stream.concat(listExon.stream(), listSup.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(obj -> {transformation})).values());

Comment: That is a typical [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have created a list `Object` type and  now dealing with instance of checks and type-casting. Instead, you can parse the data from the DB into a list of `GlobalData` in the first place, or create two separate lists (of `Sup` and `Exon`) and then generate a list of `GlobalData` based on them. Your current problem is artificial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your previous question, you're having as output a `List<List<Object>>` while now you want to map each `List<Object>` to a single `GlobalData` instance.

Mind that I'm giving you this answer only basing on the few details that I've got from your question and with no knowledge of the relationships between your classes.

```
List<GlobalData> listGlobalData = listMixed.stream()
        .map(list -> {
            //Mapping each list to a GlobalData object

            //Retrieving an object from the list to create a GlobalData 
            Object firstObj = list.stream().findFirst().orElse(null);
            if (firstObj == null) {
                return null;
            }

            //Instacing a GlobalData with IncomeCode, EndDate and CodeRef
            GlobalData gd = null;
            if (firstObj.getClass() == Exon.class) {
                Exon exon = (Exon) firstObj;
                gd = new GlobalData(exon.getIncomeCode(), exon.getEndDate(), exon.getCodeRef());
            } else {
                Sup sup = (Sup) firstObj;
                gd = new GlobalData(sup.getIncomeCode(), sup.getEndDate(), sup.getCodeRef());
            }

            //Updating the GlobalData with each object of the list 
            for (Object o: list){
                if (o.getClass() == Exon.class){
                    Exon exon = (Exon) o;
                    gd.setValue(gd.getValue().add(exon.getValue()));
                    if (exon.getXxx() > 100){
                        gd.setIncome(calcMethod(exon));
                    }
                } else {
                    Sup sup = (Sup) o;
                    gd.setValue(gd.getValue().add(sup.getValue()));
                    if (sup.getXxx() > 100){
                        gd.setIncome(calcMethod(sup));
                    }
                }
            }
            return gd;
        })
        .filter(obj -> obj != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here is also a link where I've posted my entire solution to test the code above. However, since there is an execution time limit on the server hosting the solution, the output won't be displayed, but you could check the link anyway to copy the code and test it on your machine.

I've also provided some dummy classes to mock the behavior of some of the methods shown in your example.

https://ideone.com/rN5XVa

Comment: Same thing as my code : private GlobalData toGlobalData(List<Object> objects) {...} right?

Comment: kinda, your helping method will give you a List<GlobalData> for a given  List<Object>. I don't know how common of a utility could be in your software. If it's a one time thing is better to keep it within the stream. Also, you're not flattening the stream, so you'll end up with a `List<List<GlobalData>>` instead of a `List<GlobalData>` as you wanted.

Comment: your .map(obj -> {
            if (obj instanceof Exon) {
                ...
            }
            Sup sup = (Sup) obj;
            return new GlobalData(sup.getIncomeCode(), sup.getEndDate(), sup.getCodeRef());
        }) create a GlobalData object for each stream element, but me i want to create one GlobalData Object by group, for example this list [Exon{45 2021-01-01 4}, Exon{45 2021-01-01 4}, Sup{45 2021-01-01 4}] will be transformed to one GlobalData instance after calculation on other Exon, Sup fields content

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: The method Stream::mapMulti introduced in Java 16. I'm using Java 8

Comment: instanceof is an expensive operator

Comment: @gunescelil replace it with `obj.getClass() == Exon.class` and  et voilà, you're done. Easy peasy.

Comment: @user3072470 I've provided two different solutions: one for Java 8 on and one for Java 16 on. You need to pick one of the two, not both. In your case, just use the main solution under the `Java 8 Solution section`. The one using java 16 is just an alternative.

Comment: Still can't get control over my list of objects, i have to do some business code & calculation using Exons and Sups belonging to the same sublist to construct my new GlobalData instance. codeIncome, endDate and codeRef are a few objects properties among other properties of each Exon and Sup objects which i'll use in my transformation. I need to create one GlobalData instance once then iterate the mixed sublist to fill my GlobalData instance. then move to the second mixed sublist until the nth one like in my helper method : private GlobalData toGlobalData(List<Object> objects) {...}

Comment: @user3072470 ok, but the helper method you provided does not show how to initialize a GlobalData. instance Could you maybe update your question to show an example of how a list of 3 elements (2 exon and 1 sup) would create a new GlobalData?

Comment: For this subList  [Exon{45 2021-01-01 4, more fields...}, Exon{45 2021-01-01 4, more fields ...}, Sup{45 2021-01-01 4, more fields ...}] i'll create one and only one GlobalData instance. take each element from the sublist and update this instance after doing some business verifications, calculations and transformations using this element others fields data.

Comment: @user3072470 ok, but it's the part **"take each element from the sublist and update this instance after doing some business verifications, calculations and transformations etc"** that I don't know how to write if you don't add an actual example in your question. I wanna help you and update my answer, but if you don't specify how you handle each Exon and Sup in your group to create a GlobalData I cannot write it...

Comment: I already updated my question, my toGlobalData helper method set the properties of the unique instance created before iterating the subList of mixed Exons and Subs. in your solution how can i use the same thing as toGlobalData method, i mean in the map operator i have to know when to create a new instance if all the sublist elements are consumed and move to the second sublist and create a new instance of GlobalData and update it with the subList elements after doing some business logic

Comment: @user3072470 what is getValue supposed to do for Exon, Sup and GlobalData? Can we have a definition of that too? Also, getxxx() what is it? and what should `calcMethod` return?

Comment: getValue is one of many other getters in Exon class, and Supclass getXXX means the different getters in each Class, calcMethod use many business rules to calc taxes etc..The most important thing for now is how to tell to the map operation in the stream create one instance for each sublist and give control on this list before move to the next subList..flatmap will stream element by element and don't give control on all subList elements in one loop like foreach in my toGlobalData

Comment: @user3072470 got it. What does `calcMethod` return, though? Also, what does getValue() return? If you can add the implementation of `getValue()` in your question would be great.

Comment: BigDecimal values

Comment: Thank you so much Dan, i appreciate a lot your help. I have another question which i'm trying to formulate by simplifying my use case, it is related to my previous questions.

Comment: @user3072470 sure. Let's see if it's something quick to reply or if you need to open a new question linked to the previous one